# Monitor statement verilog

Tags: verilog

Removing #2 reset after monitor statement makes the code not to work.The output just stands at 0 x. Whereas including it works fine. Why?

```
module counter(out,clock,reset);
input clock,reset;
wire clock,reset;
output [3:0]out;
reg [3:0]out; 
always @(posedge clock or negedge clock)
begin
if(reset)
    out<=1'b0;  
else
    out<=out+1;
end
endmodule

module tb();
reg clock,reset;
output [3:0]out;
counter c(out,clock,reset);
initial
begin
    clock=0;
    reset=1;
end
initial
begin
    $monitor("%d %d",$time,out);
    #2 reset=0;
end
always
    #1 clock=~clock;
initial
    #100 $finish;
endmodule
```

Comment: Why are you inferring a double edge flop? Did you intend to have an asynchronous reset?

Comment: Remove $time from your monitor, does that work?  The reason this is having a problem is that $time is changing continuously, and $monitor is being calling infinitely.

Comment: Also, you should only have 1 initial block.  The others should be always blocks or maybe fork/join.

Comment: @Russell, `$time` is not an issue with `$monitor`, it is a special case because it does not trigger an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing the `#2` you create a race condition on `reset`:

```
initial reset = 1;
initial reset = 0;
```

Simulators will often have the the final value of `reset` the last assignment read in the compiling order. Try merging you initial blocks:

```
initial
begin
    $monitor("%d %d",$time,out);
    clock=0;
    reset=1;
    #2 // <-- optional (and still recommened) if you make the below change
    // @(clk) //<-- if you truely want a dual edge triggered flip-flop with synchronous reset
    reset=0;
end
```

---

Dual edge triggered flip-flop are very uncommon and many synthesizers and FPGAs do not support them. I'm guessing you are intending to have an negative edge triggered flip-flop with an active high asynchronous reset. In this case replace:

```
always @(posedge clock or negedge clock)
```

with:

```
always @(negedge clock or posedge reset)
```